# Javascript if statement in body onload

Tags: javascript, onload

I'm just needing a little help. I'm wanting to display a success message on my index, but only if someone has come from the php page that sends the email.

This is what I have

```
<script>
function load()
{
    if (document.referrer == 'http://www.blahblah.com/contact-form-handler.php') {
        $.notify.success('We read you loud and clear; message received. Prepare for reply.', {
            autoClose : 3000
        });
    }
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="load()">
```

This works :

```
<script>
function load()
{
    $.notify.success('We read you loud and clear; message received. Prepare for reply.', {     autoClose : 3000 });
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="load()">
```

So there's obviously something wrong with that if statement. Can someone please help me?

Comment: What do you get if you do in `load()` an `alert(document.referrer)`?

Comment: maybe the if condition is never met in your tests

Comment: @Lloyd I get index.html. Mmmmm...I'll try set index.html as the referrer. But then won't it show if someone just refreshes the page?

Comment: Okay, I've got it working now, thanks to @Lloyd for the alert suggestion. And I had to remove the [link]http:///www.[link]. Only problem now is if someone has sent a message and refresh the page it shows the success message again. I can live with that though, unless someone has a fix.

Answer (score 1):

use a regular expression with `.match()`

```
function load()
{
if (document.referrer.match(/\/contact-form-handler.php/)) {
    $.notify.success('We read you loud and clear; message received. Prepare for reply.', {
        autoClose : 3000
    });
}
}
```